# Tensorflow: Load/Run multiple models with multi-thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I've searched the answer to this question but no luck.

In many applications, we have multiple trained NN models deploying on one GPU. In addition, we have to use multi-thread technology in order to get full computation power of the GPU. For example, there are two different tensorflow CNN models in my application, and I want to run (i.e., inference/deploy) them in two different thread.

Here is what I did:

```
## define my cnn model
class my_cnn_model:
    ...

## initialize two graphs 
g1 = tf.Graph()
g2 = tf.Graph()

## define two sessions and bind one cnn model to each session
sess1 = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=g1, config=cnn1_cfg)
cnn1 = my_cnn_model(..., sess1)

sess2 =tf.InteractiveSession(graph=g2, config=cnn2_cfg)
cnn2 = my_cnn_model(..., sess2)

## define two function model runs
def cnn1_model_run(g1, sess1):
    ...
    sess1.run();

def cnn2_model_run(g2, sess2):
    ...
    sess2.run();


## put the functions into two separate threads
thread_0 = threading.Thread(target= cnn1_model_run,args=...)
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target= cnn2_model_run,args=...)

## now issue the two threads
thread_0.start()
thread_1.start()
```

The results show however, the two cnn models are interfere with each other and give wrong output. Where is the problem using the above mechanism ? Is the python multi-thread function not safe for multiple tensorflow model deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fix the problem by adding `with g1.as_default():`

```
def cnn1_model_run(g1, sess1):
    with g1.as_default(), sess1.as_default():
        ...
        sess1.run();
```

Same fix in `cnn2_model_run` function.